# React + Redux: proper way to handle after-dispatch logic

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component with some internal state (e.g. isLoading) which has access to redux data. In this component I'd like to dispatch a thunk action (api request) resulting in redux data change. After the thunk is completed I need to change the state of my component. As I see it, there are two ways to do so:

1. Use the promise return by the thunk and do all I need there, e.g.

```
handleSaveClick = (id) => {
    const { onSave } = this.props;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    onSave(id).then(() => this.setState({ isLoading: false }));
};
```

2. Pass a callback to the thunk and fire it from the thunk itself, e.g.

```
  handleSaveClick = (id) => {
    const { onSave } = this.props;
    this.setState({ isLoading: true });
    onSave(id, this.onSaveSuccess);
  };
```

Which one is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The safer way is to use the promise implementation, as you'll be **sure** that function will only run after the promise has been resolved. The second implementation has no inherent flaws, but if anything in your thunk is async, then it will not work correctly since it'll run once the code is reached, not when the code above it finishes executing. When handling anything that can be async (server requests/loading data/submitting data), it's always safer to use Promise implementations.

Comment: Question on the first situation using the promise: Even though the promise is fulfilled isn't there still a risk the redux state has not yet dispatched to the component?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can ever get a guarantee that your component will get the updated redux state first. I would assume that the promise would be resolved once the action dispatched finishes, so the resolved function would run before the redux state gets updated in your components. It also really depends on what code is in the resolved function, since JS is async. If you really need to make sure you run something after the Redux state has changed, you can use componentDidUpdate(prevProps) to compare prevProps and this.props, then act accordingly.

Comment: It also shouldn't matter since as another commenter stated, connect fires rerenders for the component once the Redux state updates. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to execute code after the action dispatches, after the Redux state changes or after your component get the updated Redux values? The first one is accomplished with a promise in the thunk, and the third with componentDidUpdate. The second one shouldn't matter because the Redux state is separate from your components, you shouldn't need to care when it updates as long as it does.

Comment: Ok that’s what I thought

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best practice for updating component level state or running a callback function based on changing redux state (or any props/state changes for that matter) is to use componentDidUpdate or useEffect:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
     if(prevProps.someReduxState !== this.props.someReduxState && this.state.isLoading){
        setState({isLoading:false})
     }
}
```

With useEffect:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    if(!props.someReduxState){
         setLoading(true)
    } else {
         setLoading(false)
    }
},[props.someReduxState])
```

However, I might recommend a different approach (depending on the goal especially on initial data fetching) that manages the loading of state within redux:

Initialize your redux state with a loading value instead:

```
export default someReduxState = (state = {notLoaded:true}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.FETCH_SOME_REDUX_STATE:
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

then in your component you can check:

```
if (this.props.someReduxState.notLoaded ){
    // do something or return loading components
} else {
    // do something else or return loaded components
}
```

Comment: This looks more like worst practice. If state is being stored in redux, then handle it in redux. It already fires rerenders through `connect` so using `componentDidUpdate`there is actually terrible and unnecessary.

Comment: I agree which is why I put the "different approach" which manages the load state within redux instead of adding isLoaded to the component level state. However , if the OP wishes to manage some component state based on some state in redux then I think my answer still stands

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear with what i meant by best practice

Comment: I don't think its feasible to add or keep track a loading in Redux, it's much easier to manage it with local state. The time between Redux state updating and rerenders firing are almost negligible.

Comment: I agree that managing loading state at the component level can be useful. The latter part of the answer is helpful to avoid unnecessary renders when initially fetching and dispatching data. Managing loading state by initializing with a loading value such as `{notLoaded:true}` (it can also be reset to this value when un-mounting if the data needs to be re-loaded again)

Comment: Also (if managing loading state at the component level) no matter the method used this component will render at least three times. Once for setting state to loading, once for setting it to not loading, and once again when redux dispatches. In my opinion (and I agree the time should be negligible) from a best practice approach if you are managing a loading state based on data fetching/saving then you should set loading to false only once all data is dispatched, which would be in a useEffect or componentDidUpdate.